# Filtering for the Most Recent Log Entry Per System in Loki Over a Time Range

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki, grafana-variable, promtail, logql

I am using Grafana Loki to monitor system logs, and I need to determine when each system last sent a log entry. My goal is to identify systems that are offline. The following query identifies such systems by checking for logs in mrs_system_info and not in mrs_error_list within a certain time frame:

```
count by(system) (count_over_time({job="mrs_system_info"} [10m]))
unless
count by(system) (count_over_time({job="mrs_error_list"} [5m]))
```

This query effectively flags the systems that are considered offline, as illustrated in the linked image. However, I am running into an issue with timestamps being identical and inaccurate—merely reflecting the current time.
[image: query output]
My approach was to obtain the last log entry for each system using an additional query and then use Grafana transformations to associate them with the corresponding offline systems. However, I am encountering a challenge due to the 5000 log limit, and I need a workaround. Ideally, I would like to get just the last log entry for the job="mrs_system_info" of every system. Yet, I am unsure of the correct query for this in Loki.

Once I have the last entry for each system—for instance, for the job="mrs_error_list"—I could use transformations to pair it with the offline systems to get the correct timestamp.

How can I modify my Loki query to retrieve only the last log entry per system within a specified time range, considering the high volume of logs?

Output of the suggested solution by Vadim.
[image]

Comment: Grafana's Loki query have option to switch to Type *Instant*. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I’d like to know when each offline system last sent logs. Since the initial query (to get all systems which are offline) doesn't provide the correct timestamps, an additional query is needed to match each system's last log (using transformations). A straightforward job query produces too much output, hiding systems that last logged 7 days ago. One solution could be receiving only the last log per system for this job, but I’m unsure of the syntax. Any other solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I modify my Loki query to retrieve only the last log entry per system within a specified time range, considering the high volume of logs?

You can use `max_over_time` function. Next query returns last log timestamp for each system for the last 24h. Change query type from Range to Instant.

```
max_over_time(
  {job="mrs_system_info"}
    | label_format ts=`{{ __timestamp__ | unixEpoch }}` 
    | unwrap ts
  [24h]
) by (system)
```

If you have really high volume of log data and the query execution time is slow you can use recording rules to periodically query logs for a small time window and send results to Mimir or Prometheus.

Comment: That actually kind of works. The problem, though, is that this query returns the exact same timestamp for each system, which cannot be true, since I can check out the last log of each of these systems, and they are different. I have provided a screenshot of the result in my original question now. Do you have any idea why this is the case? I assume it has something to do with "instant". The information i need is when each of the systems sent their last log entry.

Comment: @Falke The last column (Value #A) contains the last log timestamp in unix format (number of seconds that have elapsed since the Unix epoch)